# How to display data in group format in Kendo UI mobile

Tags: kendo-mobile

How to group data with fixed header template in list view? Here is my sample code:

[jsfiddle](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/uzOM)

FYI, I don't have server grouping. I want to display data by sample_number and date_collected. Can anyone help with this.

JSON Data:
d{analytical_value:1002.0, data_collected:01/14/14, parameter:Density @15C, sample_number:"1"}

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're looking for?

Comment: Is description enough or you want me to elaborate more?

Comment: Correct, I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I want to group my data by sample number. I am able to display data on list view but when I try to group my data it's not working. My web services return JSON string which consist of sample_number, parameter, date_collected and analytical_value. The JSFiddle just shows 2 value but it consist of 100 value with same format.

Comment: Basic format to display:                                      Sample No:1                                                     Date Collected: 01/01/2014 Parameter: parameter Analytical Value: 0.5                                                                 Sample No:2                                                     Date Collected:01/01/2014 Parameter: parameter Analytical Value:0.6

Comment: I'm unable to hit your service endpoint in the jsfiddle.. You should hardcode the javascript array into the jsfiddle to remove any outside dependencies.

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService","analytical_value":"1002.0              ","date_collected":"01\/14\/14","letter":"1","parameter":"Density @ 15°C                                    "},{"__type":"Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService","analytical_value":"464.0               ","date_collected":"01\/14\/14","letter":"1","parameter":"Viscosity @ 50 °C                                 "}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/uzOM/13) is my updated code sample.

I've passed the I've passed the array `d` from the returned data to the template.

Note, in my sample, I'm use the hardcoded data you sent and not data from the service.

```
<div data-role="view" id="foo" data-init="mobileListViewHeadersInit">
   <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>

<script id="tmp" type="text/x-kendo-template">        
    #: __type # <br />
    #: date_collected #<br />
    #: parameter #<br />
    #: analytical_value #
</script>  

<script>       

  var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body);
  var ds = {"d":[{"__type":"Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService","analytical_value":"1002.0 ","date_collected":"01\/14\/14","letter":"1","parameter":"Density @ 15°C "},{"__type":"Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService","analytical_value":"464.0 ","date_collected":"01\/14\/14","letter":"1","parameter":"Viscosity @ 50 °C "}]};


  function mobileListViewHeadersInit(){
    $("#list").kendoMobileListView({
      dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: ds.d}),
        template: $("#tmp").html()          
    });
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately, I want to group those data by Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService with fix header i.e. Service1.Sample:#MobileWCFService

Comment: I was able to get fixed header list view. Is it possible to have _type and date_collected has fixed header in list view. Also, you can find my working code:   http://trykendoui.telerik.com/@Rushabh/ajaC/2

Comment: As before, we can't access your data, so *you* need to hardcode it into your samples.  I still don't know what you're asking for, but perhaps if I can see your example I'll understand...

Comment: Sample:                                                          {"d":{"analytical_value":"Pass","date_collected":"11\/13\/13","parameter":"Workmanship","sample_number":5},{"analytical_value":"<0.10","date_collected":"11\/16\/13","parameter":"Carbon Residue, Micro Carbon on 10% Bott.","sample_number":10}]}                                         I want to show list of item by group which consist of sample_number and date_collected (fix header).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll share with you my working sample. Right now, I able to get sample_number in group and trying to get data_collected. It is giving me hard time to get that. Can you suggest some alternative were I can have sample_number and date_collected occurs once and all it record appears at the bottom of it.please!